# Netbeans IDE Problem

Tags: java-me, netbeans6.1

What does the following problem in NetBeans 6.1 IDE stands for while working in J2ME (WTK 2.2)?

"builtin.ks" file/folder could not be found"

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Netbeans cant find the keystore file, it is trying to sign the files. So, Here are the instructions for 5.5 version of Netbeans, it should not be too different for 6.1.

- Right click on project select project
  properties. And then select "signing"
  in the left side list of menus. The
  UI on right will change to list
  options for keystore management.
- Click on "Open Security Manager.."
  link and in the pop up that comes up,
  click on "Add keystore" button.
- Nowcheck the radio box for "Add Existing
  Keystore" and navigate to where you
  have the file saved. Click OK to
  complete the steps.

On the other hand you can just tell Netbeans to not sign the jad/jar.

- Right click on project select project
  properties. And then select "signing"
  in the left side list of menus. The
  UI on right will change to list
  options for keystore management.
- Uncheck the box for "Sign
  Distribution" and you should be able
  to avoid this error.